# DisplayPort KVM switch not passing signal through DisplayPort to HDMI adapter

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, kvm-switch

Adapter works when connected directly to PC but now when using KVM, an illustration of the setup can be seen here:

[image: here]

with red indicating the non working connection path.

The adapter is DP to HDMI. KVM has 4 DP in and two out. I have no clue as to why I get this error and Windows 11 is unable to detect the other display.
I've tried swapping cable orders and positions, without any change.

Comment: The problem is likely chainloading one too many adapters. Probably nothing you can do other than test different hardware and/or preferably avoid converters.

Comment: is the adapter active or passive? I have a simillar rig, but had to use active adapters.

Comment: Also I'd ditch the second input for the HDMI box, and run everything through the KVM (or bypass the KVM for that monitor). the KVM in particular may become confused if you are changing the channel on the monitor.

Comment: I think it is a passive adapter. @FrankThomas do you have an example of an active one? I would greatly appreciate it.
W.r.t. the second input to the hdmi box it was purely visual. There is only one cable from the adapter to the hdmi box, but I now see how it not properly described or visualised.

Comment: so we don't do hardware recommendations, but searching the web for "Active Dp HDMI' adapter brings up many devices that clearly state that they are "active'. sorry, hope that helps.

Comment: I found one and have ordered it. I'll update my post once I've tested with the active adapter according to the results :-)

Comment: Using an active adapter solved the problem. Do you want to answer the question such that I can accept it or should I do it?

Comment: Glad it worked out for you! go ahead and answer if you like.